# stable manifold theorem proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am taking this semester a course in differential equations for dynamical systems and I need to prove the stable manifold theorem. I was trying to read it on the perko book, but is not clear for me the proof, can you help with it?. maybe another reference or something that can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can find a nice proof with lots of explanations and intermediate steps over here:

https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/the-stable-manifold-theorem/